# Volume of a triangular prism with non parallel bases

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider an $\mathbf{(v_1,v_2,v_3)}$ triangle and its $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ unit normal.
Let $\mathbf{p_i}=\lambda_i\mathbf{\hat{n}} + \mathbf{v_i}$, $i=\overline{1,3}$.

Is it possible to compute the volume of the arising prism $(\mathbf{(v_1,v_2,v_3),(p_1,p_2,p_3)}$ using calculus (e.g. a double integral) or does one have to divide the prism into 3 tetrahedra? Going for the last option will not yield a "nice" formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution (I am not 100% confident it is mathematically sound):

Define a scalar function over the $\mathbf{(v_1,v_2,v_3)} \equiv (1-s-t)v_i+sv_j+tv_k$ triangle s.t. $f(\mathbf{v_i})=\lambda_i$. This function can be a linear combination:
$$ f(\mathbf{v}(s,t))= (1-s-t)\lambda_1 + s \lambda_2 + t \lambda_3,$$
where $s\in[0,1]$ and $t\in [0,1-s]$.

Thus, $\mathbf{v}(s,t)$ is a parametrization of the aforementioned triangle.
[image]

Now, if you compute the surface integral of $f$ over this triangle using the double integral equivalent:
$$\int_{\Delta_{i,j,k}}{f dS} = \int_0^1\int_0^{1-s}{f(\mathbf{v}(s,t)) \| \frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\times \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\| ds dt}$$
you should get the volume of the generalized prism in discussion.

The norm of the cross product of the partial derivatives of the parametrization is exactly the area of the $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ base triangle. Using basic Calculus knowledge, the double integral is equal to:

$$ \mathrm{Vol} = \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3}{6}\mathcal{A}(\Delta_{v_1,v_2,v_3} )$$

If indeed true, this is pretty neat: the sought after volume is equivalent to summing up the volumes of the three tetrahedra with the $\mathbf{(v_1,v_2,v_3)}$ base and $\lambda_i$ heights.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq\lambda_3$. You may simply calculate the base area (hint: Gram-matrix) and multiply it with $\lambda_1$.  Done this, we are faced with a pyramid: it's base area is a trapezoid $p_3$, $(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)n+v_3$, $(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)n+v_2$, $p_2$; the pyramid's height is $\|(\lambda_3-\lambda_2)n+v_2-p_1\|$.

Comment: $\lambda_i$ are not necessarily equal for $i=\overline{1,3}$ - I guess that might not work as desired.

Comment: I've overlooked that, indeed.  I'll think it over.